# Text-to-Speech library for Windows Mobile

Tags: windows-mobile, compact-framework, text-to-speech

Are there any free text-to-speech libraries available for Windows Mobile? Preferably with a C# (.net CF) API.

Edit:
It basically needs to be able to read from 0.001 to 999 and a few words like “kilometers, minutes,  behind, ahead”
Sample phrases:

- “1 minute 30 seconds behind”
- “3.45 kilometers left”

I have no need for more advanced sentences.

Comment: What's your scenario?  Are you doing full SSML, with tone, diction, and cadence? or do you just want to pronounce a single word here and there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since i haven’t found any free library I decided to go with a bunch of generated wav files recorded using the SpeechSynthesizer on a desktop computer. So I’m actually using the MS Anna voice and might replace it if my app grow large enough or bump into some legal issues.

I’m combining multiple wav files to produce the numbering:

“34.5 kilometers left” =  30.wav + 4.wav + Point.wav + 5.wav + kilometers.wav + left.wav.

Answer (score 1):

Text-to-Speech is a big, interesting problem.

Seems to me, though, that you have a very specific requirement. You have a vocabulary of about 12 words, if I understand correctly. There's no way a generalized tts solution is recommended for that scope of vocabulary. Using recorded sounds seems like a much better solution.

I don't know the cut-off for the number of words, where the TTS is recommended. But it's higher than 12 words.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the cost or even if you could use it on WM but I came across the AT&T TTS a while back and thought it might be interesting to look at for a future project.

http://www.research.att.com/~ttsweb/tts/demo.php